# get status in sending data to server with jquery

Tags: jquery

I use this code for sending form to the server with `$.post()` function.

```
$.post('filepath' , {fname:fname , lname:lname} ).done(function(data){
   $('#status').html('finished');
});
```

I want show the user a messege while sending the data to the `server.done()` is for finished progress. is there any way for while sending the data??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
$('#status').html('Processing...');
$.post('filepath' , {fname:fname , lname:lname} ).done(function(data){
   $('#status').html('finished');
});
```

Edit:

```
$(document).on("ajaxStart", function(){
   $("#status").html('Processing...');
});
```

Find more on http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: yes it is work.but i want to show the message when sending data start.otherwise show the message when $.post() fire .